# UIScrollView doesn't scroll and doesn't appear on the right position

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I need a UIScrollView and a containerView to scroll the content I create. My code for that 2 items is:

```
var scrollView = UIScrollView()
var darkener = UIView()
var container = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    darkener = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    darkener.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    darkener.alpha = 0.0
    self.view.addSubview(darkener)

    scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height+1)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)


    container = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, scrollView.frame.height, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height))
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    container.layer.masksToBounds = true
    container.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    scrollView.addSubview(container)
}
```

The problem is that the container view once I Set the Y point to scrollView.frame.height doesn't appear on the screen (it's on the bottom), but in a previous VC that code worked perfectly.

Also, it does not let me scroll on the content. What's wrong there?

If necessary I can upload the implementation, but this I think has no problem.

Comment: You've tagged this with 'objective-c' but you have Swift code posted. You might find more help if you remove the tag and add swift.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just had to put that at the end of the ViewDidLoad to declare de frame:

The textField is the final label I have on the screen, to declare the limit of the screen.

```
self.container.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.container.frame.origin.y, self.container.frame.width, textField2.frame.origin.y + textField2.frame.height - 60)
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.container.frame.width, self.container.frame.height + 20.0)
```

And works Ok now.